# Express router not working for post requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, mean-stack

I'm getting started with the whole MEAN Stack thing. I'm putting together a small test / beginners app to learn the basics. I'm currently trying to the express router for different routes. I'm having some trouble getting the routes working correctly.

When I go to localhost:8000/api it works just fine. But when I try to access `localhost:8000/api/users` it returns a `404` error :(

Here's my code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var morgan = require('morgan'); 
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000; 
var User = require('./app/models/user');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/ApiDataBase');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) 
{
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, \
22 Authorization');
  next();
});

app.use(morgan('dev'));

// testing if express runs

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome to this awesome site!');
});

// creating new instance of the router

var apiRouter = express.Router();

apiRouter.use(function(req, res, next){

  console.log('Somebody came to vist');

  next();
});

// testing the router

apiRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json({ message: 'WWWUUUUHHÚÚÚ Welcome!'});
});

// I'm not getting this part to work

apiRouter.route('/users')

  .post(function(req, res) {

    var user = new User();

    user.name = req.body.name;
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.password = req.body.password;

    user.save(function(err) {
        if(err){

            if(err.code == 11000)
                return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Þessi notandi er þegar til'});
            else
                return res.send(err);
        }

            res.json({ message: 'Notandi stofanður'});
    });


})

app.use('/api', apiRouter);

app.listen(8000);
console.log('Magic happens on port' + port);
```

Comment: I noticed that you use post method for '/users'. Therefore, it will never return html page on browser.

Comment: As far as I understood, he wants to use POST, not GET, in `/api/users` because he's saving the User in mongoose within the block :)

Answer (score 4):

> when I try to access localhost:8000/api/users it returns a 404 error

You don't have a `GET` route to `localhost:8000/api/users`, you have a `POST` route to it:

```
apiRouter.route('/users')

  .post(function(req, res) {
```

That said, when you send a `GET` request to `localhost:8000/api/users`, express can't find the route, because you it doesn't exist. You should test it against a `POST` request.

Comment: Yeah, sorry my bad. I've been hacking on my keyboard too long so I keep making silly mistakes like this. I might be able to test the post request with Postman.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring twice the endpoint '/', once in your `app.get('/'...)` and once more in `apiRouter.get('/'...`

Delete this block and it should work:

```
// testing the router
apiRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json({ message: 'WWWUUUUHHÚÚÚ Welcome!'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its reason may be the installation error ,Just **re-install the express-grnerator**.

You can Install it by using the following command on terminal .

• npx install express-generator --hbs

--hbs means view engine handlebar